# JSON indexing TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, django

I am indexing from an API JSON response that looks like the following:

```
[{
    "id": 1
    "name": "Gimbal HQ",
    "addressLineOne": "5775 Morehouse Drive, San Diego CA 92121",
    "geoFenceCircle": {
        "radius": 100,
        "visibility": "ORGANIZATION",
        "location": {
            "latitude": 32.89494374592149,
            "longitude": -117.19603832579497
        }
    },
    "placeAttributes": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    }
},
{
    "id": 3291
    "name": "Gimbal R&D",
    "addressLineOne": "5665 Morehouse Drive, San Diego CA 92121",
    "geoFencePolygon": {
        "visibility": "ORGANIZATION",
        "locations": [
            {
                "latitude": 32.8953153522896,
                "longitude": -117.19559844351653
            },
            {
                "latitude": 32.8954009341414,
                "longitude": -117.19516929007415
            },
            {
                "latitude": 32.89564867061472,
                "longitude": -117.1949815354431
            },
            {
                "latitude": 32.89545949009762,
                "longitude": -117.19463284827117
            },
            {
                "latitude": 32.894986537037255,
                "longitude": -117.19496544218902
            },
            {
                "latitude": 32.894864920127866,
                "longitude": -117.19554479933623
            }
        ]
    },
    "placeAttributes": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    }
}]
```

Thats all fine and dandy. But my issue is with my code, specifically this line:

```
for geofence in geofences:
        obj, created = Geofence.objects.get_or_create(name=geofence['name'])
```

I seem to be raising the following error:

```
21:17:17 web.1  |     obj, created = Geofence.objects.get_or_create(name=geofence['name'])
21:17:17 web.1  | TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I can't really figure out what the issue is, can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: It seems that `geofences` isn't what you think it is.  The error suggests you've hit a string, and not the expected dictionary.

Comment: Just double checked in terminal, and geofences is actually an altered (different information, not format) version of the JSON. So geofences IS what I think it is. Unless I am missing something..

Comment: if `geofences` is a list of dictionaries then you shouldn't be seeing `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

Comment: You should show the code that gets geofences. Are you parsing it from a string anywhere?

Comment: hello, please describe your question more in detail or if you got the answer then please update it.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to check geofence object data type.

It look like it is a array not a map.

Comment: Yes I am indexing as if it is a list, how is that not correct?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to put an index infront of name index. try:

`obj, created = Geofence.objects.get_or_create(name=geofence[0]['name'])`

Answer (score 0):

Your string data of JSON format is broken( `,` is missing twice after each `id` key ):

```
[{
"id" : 1
"name" : "Gimbal HQ",
"addressLineOne" : "5775 Morehouse Drive, San Diego CA 92121"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are accessing a dict into a list.

```
for geofence in geofences:
        obj, created = Geofence.objects.get_or_create(name=geofence[geofence].get('name'))
```

here `['geofence']` refers to the index of for loop which will select list object and to access dict object you can write `get()` method in python. The main benefit of this is it will  always return.